# Ubuntu 22.04.1 bypassing browser download settings

Tags: 22.04

The Ubuntu 22.04.1 update appears to be bypassing my browser download settings. I'm using Firefox 103.0.2 and have set a specific folder on an external drive under "Save files to".
Since the update all my downloads go to the Downloads folder on my C-drive instead. I have deleted the Downloads folders from Home and from Files, and when I tried downloading a file a Downloads folder was automatically created in Home and the download went into that.
When I tick "Always ask you where to save files" that function works fine; when I untick it and leave the location of my preferred save location it reverts to sending the files to the Downloads folder.

Comment: This is probably due to Firefox being a _snap_. Are you using the _snap_ version of Firefox?

Comment: This is a known bug: The Firefox Snap (new in 22.04) lacks permission to save files outside your /home directory. This is a security feature. Work on the bug is in progress, but slow as several security-related elements of the system are involved. Your current options are to revise your workflow, to change your mountpoint, or to use a different (non-Snap) browser.

Comment: Thank you both so much, I do remember seeing "Snap" during the update process. Guess I'll have to stick with Always ask till it's sorted :)